# Tap gesture recognizer gets triggered when user taps scroll view to stop scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

In the gif below I'm scrolling fast (by flicking) then tapping the display to stop the scrolling, this triggers the tap recognizer (hides/shows the tool bar). I only want the tap recognizer to get triggered when the scrollview isn't being scrolled, is there a way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround the gives the same result I'm looking for.
Just disable tap gesture recognizer in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` and then enable it again in `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:`.